# Firebase: Permission denied

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

> 2017-10-22 18:18:02.498 studycook[17238] 
>   [Firebase/Database][I-RDB038012] setValue: or removeValue: at
>   /users/user_id/test/abc
>   failed: permission_denied

The security settings for /users/$uid are as follows:

```
".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid || auth != null && root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() == true",
".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid || auth != null && root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() == true"
```

What am I doing wrong?
My code:

```
ref.child("users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)/test/abc").setValue("true")
```

Comment: On `/users` there will be no variable `$uid`. You probably want these rules on `/users/$uid`.